# How to pass a function as an optional parameter Swift

Tags: swift

New to Swift and I am currently getting around passing a function as an optional parameter in the following way:

```
import Foundation 

func foo()
{
    print("Foo")
}

func bar()
{
    print("Bar")
}

func dummy()
{
    return
}

func myFunc()
{
    myFunc(callBack: dummy())
}

func myFunc(callBack: (Void))
{
    foo()
    callBack
}

myFunc()
myFunc(callBack: bar())
```

i.e. exploiting polymorphism

This seems like an inelegant way to do this, is there a better way,

Thanks,
Tom

edit:

I am aware I could shorten this by doing:

```
import Foundation 

func foo()
{
    print("Foo")
}

func bar()
{
    print("Bar")
}

func dummy()
{
    return
}

func myFunc(callBack: (Void) = dummy())
{
    foo()
    callBack
}

myFunc()
myFunc(callBack: bar())
```

But I would still say this is an inelegant solution

Comment: `(Void)` doesn't make sence here, function type that accept nothing and returns nothing would be `() -> Void`.

Comment: @Moritz Noted and fixed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can easily define a default value for a function as parameter:

```
func foo(completion: () -> Void = { }) {
    completion()
}
```

You could also have it be nil by default:

```
func foo(completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
```

When it's an optional closure, you'll have to call it like this:

```
completion?()
```

Comment: I would not have guessed that is what you meant at all. Anyway, +1 since I think this maybe the "elegant" thing OP wants.

Comment: It seems like it is, yes. Thanks!

Comment: This is what I was after, seems to be more "elegant" in my opinion, thanks!

Comment: How do I pass a parameter to the completion handler?

Comment: @AkshatTiwari you can do this in the function declaration: `completion: (_ x: Int) -> Void = { _ in }` and then call it like this `completion(5)`. I think these don't accept named parameters. Xcode will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Your are referring to [default arguments](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID169):

> You can define a default value for any parameter in a function by assigning a value to the parameter after that parameter’s type. If a default value is defined, you can omit that parameter when calling the function.

So you need something like:

```
func myfunc (callback: ()->void = dummy) {
```

[LinusGeffarth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53391622/how-to-pass-a-function-as-an-optional-parameter-swift/53391688?noredirect=1#comment93659577_53391688) notes that callbacks in Swift are called *completion*, or *closure* as [avismara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1950419/avismara) notes.

Comment: Not exactly, see the added snippet above, default and optional parameters are not the same thing

Comment: @thoxey See edit. You are not specifying the type of a function correctly.

Comment: @thoxey It is getting unclear what you want to do, and "inelegant" is in no way a good specification. I assume you are talking about something similar to Java or such - which will have its own overhead, such as checking if the optional parameter was specified. Having a `dummy` no-op in your case (I would actually use a closure) seems like the most "elegant" solution to me.

Comment: In swift, callbacks are usually called `completion`.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth I wanted to use OPs naming convention, but I'll add you comment as info in the question.

Comment: Thanks. We'd also tell OP to have their class names be capitalized and properties lowercased, right? OP's "convention" is simply not suitable for this language. Hence, we should tell them.

Comment: Also, your code is very pseudo-y. I think it'd help OP more if you added actual code.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth I am not sure. I dislike turning answers into a tutorial session, except maybe some specific cases of well researched homework. I am also unsure how much tutoring you are exactly expecting - I suggest you provide your own answer instead if mine is insufficient - you can elaborate on best practices if you see fit there.

Comment: I was hoping since the function is void there might be some kind of default dummy/noop function, as I said new to swift so wasn't sure on the best way to do this, it seems though that defining a noop is best

Comment: Adding another answer is a little redundant... Indeed, OP hasn't done (any) research, apparently, because there are tons of answers on completion handlers. Anyway, I think an answer isn't really an answer if OP's trying to find a specific line, yet the answer only provides their code again.

Comment: @thoxey - could you be referring to Swift closures?

Comment: My two cents: In Swift they aren't really called completion -- they sometimes are based on the context -- but in general they are called closures. :)

Comment: @LinusGeffarth If you think this is a bad answer downvote. If the question is without an answer and you have one please feel free to provide your own.

Answer (score 2):

Full code with answer applied:

```
import Foundation 

func foo()
{
    print("Foo")
}

func bar()
{
    print("Bar")
}

func myFunc(completion: () -> Void = { })
{
    foo()
    completion()
}

myFunc()
myFunc(completion: bar)
```

Answer (score 1):

Umm, are you passing function as an optional parameter, though? It looks like you have written a method that accepts `Void`, you have a function that accepts `Void` and you are just calling that method. I don't see any trace of polymorphism here except probably that the `myFunc` has multiple signatures. This method is an inelegant solution not because it is inelegant, but because it isn't a solution.

Here is a correct example of polymorphism in functional systems:

```
func printA() {
    print("A")
}

func printB() {
    print("B")
}

//This method accepts a function as a parameter
func higherOrderPrinter(with print: () -> Void ) { 
    print() //Can be anything, depends on the method you send here. Polymorphism much? :)
}

higherOrderPrinter(with: printA) //Prints A. See carefully how I am NOT doing printA()
higherOrderPrinter(with: printB) //Prints B
//In fact...
higherOrderPrinter {
    print("C") 
} //Prints C
```

Comment: Do you have to specify and create it as a separate function then pass it to the parameter? I could not find a way to just declare the function right away rather than making a function with function name.